# WARNING: Failed to read manifest from java.io.IOException: invalid header field

Tags: java, tomcat

While running with TOMCAT server below error is getting.

How to resolve it?

> WARNING: Failed to read manifest from [C:\JavaWebApplications.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\includeapp\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF]
>   java.io.IOException: invalid header field
>
> SEVERE: Error while attempting to validate required application extensions
>   java.io.IOException: invalid header field